# Send highlighted text to cordova app from other app

Tags: json, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

Is it possible to highlight text in another app (eg. browser) and send the highlighted text to my intel xdk cordova app as json to be used? (using a context menu for example)

Answer (score 0):

If by that you mean copy and paste in a cordova app, then this plugin may do the trick:

https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard

I haven't tried it myself, so caveat emptor, but it looks like it will do what you need.  It enables paste and copy so you should be able to highlight text in one app, copy to the clipboard, then paste it into your app.

I'm not sure what you mean by sending the text "as json", but if the text you're sending conforms to the JSON standard, then you could convert it to an object using `JSON.parse()`.  Otherwise you'll need to parse the string yourself to get what you want out of it.

Comment: i mean like evernote...so for example a user highlights text in a app i see the options ('copy','paste','select all' and 'send to MyApp'

Comment: I guess I haven't seen something like that.  If you have some idea how it's done in native apps you might be able to use that info to search for a cordova plugin to do it.